# Como puedo justificar a la dercha o izquierda en una gráfica en R

Tags: r, ajustar-texto

Quiero agregar el nombre del archivo cuyos datos están siendo graficados en un histograma y colocarlo al calce de la hoja. Puede ser izquierda o derecha.

Comment: Bienvenido Ovidio Carlos Molina Chapa a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy escueta y sinceramente muy ambigua ¿De que sistema gráfico estas hablando? ¿base? ¿ggplot? ¿lattice? ¿Que texto? ¿un título, un subtitulo, una etiqueta, una fuente? Por favor, agrega un mínimo ejemplo de código para que podamos ayudarte. Sludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tocayo , para graficos rapidos en R usa el paquete ESQUISSE() es muy facil de usar solo arrastras y sueltas . Es lo mejor si eres nuevo en R. En youtube hay tutoriales de como descargarlo y usarlo bien.